# Can't use velocity to compute positions within blend tree

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I select Velocity XZ to compute positions within a blend tree, it gives me this error:

Could not compute threshold for 'Blend Tree' there is not enough data
UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)

I can't really come up with anything to try :/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.